# Wireless router in office network

Tags: networking, router

I have connected a wireless router (B) to the wired lan network (A) in the office.

The router is cloning the MAC address of my PC to get internet access and provides password protected wireless network (B) for mobile phones.

SSID not distributed and DHCP is active.

Is there any possible way that my router (B) can provide IP address to the other computers in the office network (A)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its always possible. You can however be reasonably sure its safe if you do it right.

- If you accidentally connect the LAN ports to your office network,
  you'll definitely hijack the office DHCP.
- Some (usually older) routers were built with buggy DHCPd instances
  which would offer DHCP in response to requests seen on the WAN port.

If you don't have either of those problems, you're probably okay.

Unless you're trying to be stealthy for some reason (insert usual "bad idea" lecture), the best way to prevent DHCP leakage is to configure your router as a simple AP -- that is, bridged mode with DHCP turned off. As a bridge, your router no longer issues its own IP addresses and does not do NAT, but simply becomes a pass through much like a desktop network switch.

Comment: My wifi router is a ds-link wr300n and it is connected to the office network via the WAN port. As the internet access is limited to certain IPs I need a seperate subnet.
Is it still possible to "confuse" the DHCP server ot the office network?

Comment: Maybe. Easiest way to tell without risking the office network is to unplug the WAN port from the office and plug it into your laptop (with wifi and other connections disabled)... You should not be able to get a valid DHCP address this way (the 169.254.x.x address Windows eventually defaults to is not DHCP).
If you're comfortable with tools like Wireshark, you can also sniff said connection for any DHCP OFFER packets.